# How can I compile a C++ program with root library includes using g++?

Tags: c++, g++, root-framework

I have written a C++ program (`mainPixelDet1.C` that uses a class defined in `PixelDet1.C`), that works in root's interactive mode.

But now I want to compile it outside root, using g++.

Here's what I write on the Terminal:

```
g++ -o main mainPixelDet1.C PixelDet1.C `root-config --cflags --glibs`
```

And here's what I get:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGraf3d
>   usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPostscript
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPhysics
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Add the `-L` specifying the directory where those libraries are located.  If they are in different directories, you might need  more than one `-L`

Comment: Side note: C++ programs should be written in files that use the `.cpp` extension, for clarity and to tell the compiler easily whether it needs to compile as c++. `.c` tends to be used for C

Comment: @foips this convention doesn't necessarily hold for ROOT. In particular, the interactive mode _isn't standards-complaint C++_, it's just something that borrows heavily form the syntax. Personally, I'd prefer that code written for interactive ROOT have the `.C` extension, since it emphasizes where it came from.

Comment: @Shep Oh, for the life of me I don't think I'd seen the ROOT tag in this when I originally posted, apologies

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to also include `--ldflags` to `root-config`, so that `root-config` will supply the necessary library flag arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just solved it installing these libraries: `"libroot-*"`, `"root-plugin-*"`,`"ttf-root-installer"`.`
I find the answer on ROOT forum if you interested, here is the link:
https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=16352.
To install the library, you can write on terminal the follow command line:

```
sudo apt-get install nameoflibrary
```